# Trying to connect to command prompt and perform put operation

Tags: c#

I am trying to access command prompt from c# code and want to do FTP to get and put files form the ftp server. by using the following code I am able to connect to the FTP server. However, the put command is not working. Please assist.

```
        var process = new Process {StartInfo = startInfo};
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd "+localPath);
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"dir");
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"ftp "+serverURL);
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@""+username);
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@""+password);
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd "+serverPath);
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"put "+fileName);
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"bye");
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");

        process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: What is the output you get from the process after each line you sent?

Comment: You seem to be hammering the standard input as fast as you can without waiting for a response. Maybe try adding some delays or checking the standard out to see what response you get.

Comment: All the writelines seems overly complicated.  You should be able to build a string and do it all at once:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Comment: @Ron Beyer, I tired putting System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2300); to know where exactly its failing and the code seems to hang at the put +filename  command

Comment: Have you you tried running the commands manually from the command prompt to ensure this isn't e.g. a networking issue?

Comment: @cronburg, yes it works fine manually...

Comment: Perhaps the `fileName` variable is a null string / empty when you do it from C#? Try printing that variable to stdout.

Comment: A 0 byte file with the same file name is created on the mentioned location, but the process is not getting completed.

Comment: Try executing ftp with `ftp -dv` to get verbose / debugging info.

Comment: @cronburg, following is what i get, but the request timesout after this 230 User glads logged in.
---> CWD /interfaces/R3D/ediout/RPABOTS/outbound/
250 CWD command successful.
---> XPWD
257 "/interfaces/R3D/ediout/RPABOTS/outbound" is current directory.
---> PORT 19,39,44,158,242,182
200 PORT command successful.
---> STOR birthdaylist.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. Do you have write permission in serverPath?  (Being able to connect does not mean that you do.)
2. Immediately before the put, set the transfer mode

   process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"binary");

Otherwise please describe system responses... "is not working" could mean "does not respond (times out)", "returns error XXX", "finishes, appearing to succeed but file is not transferred" etc.

Comment: I have the permissions, tried using Binary did not work, and by saying not working ...i wanted to say the request is timing out, but it works manually when i am doing the same.Apologies for the incomplete info